# How can an image be displayed in center of the screen instead of a relative position?

Tags: css

In the next piece of code when I click the word "word" the image "image.png" appear, surrounded by some text "text text", but the position is relative to the word "word". How can I make this assembly (image surrounded by the text) to appear in the center of the screen, not relatively attached to the position of the word "word" ?

```css
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:active span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
}
```

```html
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb" style="text-decoration:none">word
    <span>text text <img src="/image.png"></span></a>
```

Comment: change absolute with fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position: relative;` from `.thumbnail`, then apply the standard centering technique showcased below:

```css
.thumbnail {
  z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:active span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
}
```

```html
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb" style="text-decoration:none">word
    <span>text text <img src="/image.png"></span></a>
```